# Converting numbers to string and back using strstream C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, casting, stream

I have a program that requires me to send numbers over a network. I'm attempting to convert them into a string and then back again using strstream. The issue I'm having is that when it comes to taking the values off of the stream I seem to be reading the incorrect number of bytes. I suspect its probably due to the initial string conversion but I'm not exactly sure. Does anybody know what's wrong?

My code is as follows

```
int data1 = 98;
float data2 =  0.5f;

std::strstream stream;
stream << data1 << data2;

string networkData = stream.str();  //assume this line is the string transferred over the network


char numberBuffer[4];
int ReadData1;
float ReadData2;

std::strstream otherStream;
otherStream << networkData;

otherStream.read(&numberBuffer[0], sizeof(int));   //reads 980.f
ReadData1 = atoi(numberBuffer);    //prodces 980

otherStream.read(&numberBuffer[0], sizeof(float));  //reads 5 followed by junk
ReadData2 = atof(numberBuffer);
```

Comment: You should be sending the data over as binary bytes, not strings. If you continue using strings then you may need to length prefix them so you know how many characters to read.

Comment: Or put a space between numbers...

Comment: Are you using specific library too send data over network? Are you allowed to use any library ? Google protocol buffers can help in abstracting  such details.

Comment: Furthermore string representations are (generally) larger and will not maintain precision (i.e., floating-point) when ultimately converted to binary values.

Comment: @JamesAdkison he may need to send between little endian and big endian, sending as text is a possible solution.

Comment: @SHR Yes, but I'd argue that binary is better. Platform independence can be achieved using a platform independent binary encoding (e.g., always use big endian).

Comment: In any event I just wanted to highlight that a binary representation has its advantages, in case OP wasn't aware of this technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing the two formatted values to the stream, with nothing to separate them, the stream contains

```
980.5
```

You read `sizeof(int)` bytes back for some reason; if there are four bytes in an `int`, then you get `980.`, which `atof` converts to `980` ignoring the `.`. Then you read `sizeof(float)` bytes, giving the remaining `5`, then garbage since you've reached the end of the stream.

One approach is to write them with a space to separate the values:

```
stream << data1 << ' ' << data2;
```

and read them back using formatted input:

```
otherStream >> ReadData1 >> ReadData2;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
otherStream.read(&numberBuffer[0], sizeof(int));
ReadData1 = atoi(numberBuffer);
```

On your platform, `sizeof(int)` is going to be either 4 or 8 bytes. Of course, a number like:

```
1234567890
```

Is ten character long, ten bytes, and this won't, obviously, read all of it. You will end up with either 1234, or 12345678, depending on your platform.

Comment: That depends on the format of the file you're reading. If the number is followed by a space, std::istream should handle it all on its own. If the number is followed by some other character, you will have to read the std::istream, character by character, until the entire number is read, as text, and then convert it to a numerical value using atoi(), or something else.

Answer (score -1):

You're picking out the values as if they were binary-encoded into the stream, but they're not. They're human-readable, ASCII representations. You seem to understand this when you apply `atoi` and `atof` but you've picked out the values as if they *were* in their binary format, with your use of `sizeof`.

Your line protocol is going to need some way to separate values and you're going to need to parse them. Or your line protocol could binary-encode the data in the first place, though then you need to set conventions with respect to data type width, encoding and endianness.